# SSRS - How to display the each column count on every column groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, msbi

I have a SSRS matrix report. In this report I want to display the column count on every column. I am using ReportBuilder 3.0 for this.

Based on the column group count I need to perform a calculation/expression.

Comment: How do you want to display this column count?  The number of items in the column? Or the number of columns you have? Or the individual index of each column in the report?  Also, how does the "column group count" feature in the "column count" - are they not two separate things?

Comment: I need column count like " number of columns I having". If I use 
CountDistinct(Fields!MM.Value, "DataSet3") I am getting total column count, but I need to display the column count on each column like 1,2,3,4,5....